# What is the equivalence of tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention in TensorFlow 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, seq2seq

I've recently working on some code written in tensorflow 1.0.1 and i want to make it available on tenorflow 2.
I am not very familiar with seq2seq.
Thank you very much.

```py
(attention_keys,
attention_values,
attention_score_fn,
attention_construct_fn) = tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention(
    attention_states=attention_states,
    attention_option="bahdanau",
    num_units=self.decoder_hidden_units,
)
```

Comment: Possibly [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/BahdanauAttention)

Answer (score 0):

As per this [Github Comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/11199#issuecomment-312410942), `tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention()` is renamed as `tf.contrib.seq2seq.DynamicAttentionWrapper`.

As per this [Github Tensorflow Commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/8cc451c2a599ab0ce127875832c20e0155553a9d), `DynamicAttentionWrapper` has been renamed to `AttentionWrapper`.

So, in 1.15, the Function equivalent to `tf.contrib.seq2seq.prepare_attention()` is [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper).

The function equivalent to [`tf.contrib.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.15/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper) in **Tensorflow 2.x** is [`tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper`](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper).

Please find this [Tensorflow Documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/AttentionWrapper) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

First install tensorflow addons using:

```
pip install tensorflow-addons
```

Then import it in your program:

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa
```

And use:

```
tfa.seq2seq.AttentionWrapper
```